How to get this value from sql query
I have a query that returns the following data



itemid
referencecategory
referenceid
batch




1234
3
209399
2404000183


4567
3
208992
2404000122


1234
21
T041531
2404000183


1234
22
T041452
2404000183


4567
22
T041427
2404000122


4567
21
T041433
2404000122



How I can get something like this?



itemid
referencecategory
referenceid
batch
originalref




1234
3
209399
2404000183
209399


1234
21
T041531
2404000183
209399


1234
22
T041452
2404000183
209399


4567
3
208992
2404000183
208992


4567
21
T041427
2404000183
208992


4567
22
T041433
2404000183
208992



Basically where the referencecategory is 21 or 22, I want to show the value of referenceid for referencecategory 3 against each row (where itemid/batch match) - hope that makes sense!
Thanks in advance

You can apply LEFT JOIN with same table with condition to have same itemid & batch & filter left joined table with referencecategory = 3.
In case you have additional referencecategory for ex. 25, 26 etc. and you only wish to apply logic for 21 & 22 only then add one more condition with ON statement as AND t1.referencecategory IN (21, 22)
Use ISNULL(t2.referenceid, t1.referenceid) AS originalref in SELECT.
Complete query is as below.
SELECT *, ISNULL(t2.referenceid, t1.referenceid) AS originalref
FROM YOUR_TABLE t1
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE t2
    ON t1.itemid = t2.itemid -- Match itemid value
        AND t1.batch = t2.batch -- Match batch value
        AND t2.referencecategory = 3 -- filter for reference category 3 from which referenceid is expected
        AND t1.referencecategory IN (21, 22) -- Additional condition if you wish to apply logic for referencecategory 21 & 22 only. If it is expected to apply for all referencecategory then remove this condition


OP specially mentioned 21 and 22.  This query would bring in all reference categories outside of 21 and 22 and assign them the reference category 3 as the original ref.

You could use conditional analytic function Max() Over() partitioned by ITEMID, BATCH:
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    your_resultset ( ITEMID,    REFERENCECATEGORY, REFERENCEID, BATCH ) AS 
        ( Select 1234,   3,  '209399',  2404000183 From Dual Union All
          Select 4567,   3,  '208992',  2404000122 From Dual Union All
          Select 1234,  21,  'T041531', 2404000183 From Dual Union All
          Select 1234,  22,  'T041452', 2404000183 From Dual Union All
          Select 4567,  22,  'T041427', 2404000122 From Dual Union All
          Select 4567,  21,  'T041433', 2404000122 From Dual 
        )

--      S Q L :
Select    ITEMID,   REFERENCECATEGORY, REFERENCEID, BATCH,
          Max(Case When REFERENCECATEGORY = 3 Then REFERENCEID End) 
              Over(Partition By ITEMID, BATCH) as ORIGINALREF
From      your_resultset
Order By  ITEMID, REFERENCECATEGORY, BATCH

/*      R e s u l t : 
    ITEMID REFERENCECATEGORY REFERENCEID      BATCH ORIGINALREF
---------- ----------------- ----------- ---------- -----------
      1234                 3 209399      2404000183 209399 
      1234                21 T041531     2404000183 209399 
      1234                22 T041452     2404000183 209399 
      4567                 3 208992      2404000122 208992 
      4567                21 T041433     2404000122 208992 
      4567                22 T041427     2404000122 208992      */

